# keyError in Django. During template rendering

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

Sorry if its a noob code or question. I am doing pagination using django-pagination and I am doing it like this.But this gives me keyError at on my page furthermore it mentions that its an error during template rendering. What I am doing wrong here.I have successfully installed pagination, modified the settings.py file. But i dont know what i need to do here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 <table class="active_table"  summary="active_user">
    <thead>
     <tr><th>Name</th><th>Mobile Number</th><th>Count</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_content">
     {% load pagination_tags %}
       {% block content %}
         {% autopaginate response_data 5 %}
           {% for b in response_data %}
              <tr class="table_rows"><td>{{ b.name }}</td><td>{{ b.mobile_number }}</td><td>{{ b.count }}</td></tr>
           {% endfor %}
         {% paginate %}
        {% endblock %}
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

The detailed traceback is pasted here http://dpaste.com/919526/

The viewcode is following

## views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
```

def active_user_table(request, b):
    if request.method != "GET":
       raise Http404

```
if (b=='4'):
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("SELECT core_user.id, name,mobile_number,COUNT(*) as count, created FROM core_user,core_useractivity WHERE core_user.id = core_useractivity.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count DESC")
         response_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
         return render_to_response("siteadmin/active_user_table.tmpl",{'response_data':response_data})
elif (b=='3'):
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("SELECT core_user.id, name, mobile_number, COUNT(*) as count, created FROM core_user, core_useractivity WHERE core_user.id = core_useractivity.user_id AND MONTH(CAST(created as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(cast(created as date)) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count DESC")
         response_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
         return render_to_response("siteadmin/active_user_table.tmpl",{'response_data': response_data})
elif (b=='2'):
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("SELECT core_user.id, name, mobile_number, COUNT(*) as count, created FROM core_user, core_useractivity WHERE core_user.id = core_useractivity.user_id AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), created) <= 7 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count DESC")
         response_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
         return render_to_response("siteadmin/active_user_table.tmpl",{'response_data': response_data})
elif (b=='1'):
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.execute("SELECT core_user.id, name, mobile_number, COUNT(*) as count, created FROM core_user, core_useractivity WHERE core_user.id = core_useractivity.user_id AND DATE(created) = DATE(NOW())")
         response_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
         return render_to_response("siteadmin/active_user_table.tmpl",{'response_data': response_data})
else:
         raise Http404
```

Sorry I am not using django ORM as of now but I will do so in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it myself but thanks to ndpu for helping me atleast I got confident there were no other issue but some settings issue. In this question [I have problems with setting up django-pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718328/i-have-problems-with-setting-up-django-pagination?rq=1).  Alasdair had mentioned adding "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth", to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS . On just adding it I am getting the correct expected values.

Answer (score 4):

You must add **context_instance** in render_to_response call:

```
return render_to_response("siteadmin/active_user_table.tmpl",{'response_data': response_data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

or you can use **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS** tuple in your settings.py. Add this string "django.core.context_processors.request" to context processors and every RequestContext will contain a variable request.

Comment: I have added those contents to my settings.py. This is what I have added -:

  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
 )
What I want to ask is even then I need to add context_instance=RequestContext(request) to my render_to_reponse.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using the [render shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)
and still facing this error, just add `{'request': request }` to the context variable

```
context = { ..., 'request':request}
return render(request, 'templatename.html', context)
```

Comment: What this will do? I mean what case this caters to?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I was facing the same error, but i was rendering my responses using the `render` shortcut; not the `render_to_response` method used by the OP. the cause of the error is still the same; i.e the templating system could not find the `request` variable. just inserting that variable in the context solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this error earlier. I was getting following error:
Internal Server Error: /cancel-email/

```
Internal Server Error: /cancel-email/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 506, in parse
    compile_func = self.tags[command]
KeyError: 'static'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/recruiter-new/recruiter/scheduler.py", line 803, in cancelEmail
    return render(request,'scheduler/cancel-email-part.html',{"cancel_email" :EmailDetail})
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 96, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 32, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 40, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name, dirs), self)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 190, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name, dirs)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 157, in find_template
    name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 46, in get_template
    contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 189, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 230, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 508, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
  File "/home/kashif/recEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 568, in invalid_block_tag
    "or load this tag?" % (token.lineno, command)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 74: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
[07/Aug/2018 08:43:26] "POST /cancel-email/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20789
```

I tried some google solutions but couldn't resolved, then finally again check my code and found a silly mistake on template file.

Just add:

```
{% load static %}
```

on top of your template file.